# Is there a comprehensive list of attributes and properties for the default Shiny slider?

Tags: r, properties, shiny, attributes, slider

Shiny makes use of the [ion-rangeslider](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/tree/master/inst/www/shared/ionrangeslider). I figured out how to modify some of its attributes. The code below changes the button color and the background color of the label above the button, and also removes the slider bar. I need to make additional changes, but am not sure which other slider attributes I can change--and how they should be referred to.

Is there a comprehensive list of this slider's attributes (such as ".irs-slider") and their properties? (E.g., for the attribute .irs-slider: "width"; "height"; "top"; "background", etc.)

**Update**: [GJPLatten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8284846/gjplatten)'s suggestion to right-click the slider in the browser and select "Inspect Element" saved my day. However, I'm still interested in finding a comprehensive list of attribute and property names which also provides descriptive information, since this would be easier to navigate and work with.

---

[image: Modified Shiny slider]

---

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("default",
              "Default slider",
              min = 0,
              max = 50,
              value = 20),
  sliderInput("modified",
              "Modified slider",
              min = 0,
              max = 50,
              value = 20),
  tags$style(type = "text/css",
             HTML(".js-irs-1 .irs-slider { width: 8px; height: 20px; top: 20px; background: green }",
                  ".js-irs-1 .irs-bar { display: none }",
                  ".js-irs-1 .irs-bar-edge { display: none }",
                  ".js-irs-1 .irs-single { color: black; background: transparent }"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parts within the HTML() function are all css. W3schools have a great tutorial on this at https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp. You can get the element name by right clicking on the element in your browser and clicking inspect element.

Comment: Thanks! I had never used "Inspect Element" before, and using it has opened up a whole new world to me. I will leave my question unresolved for a while to see if anyone knows if there is a comprehensive list somewhere, which would be a little easier to work with (and easier to "inspect").